# How does Meteor use Mori?

Tags: meteor, clojurescript, mori

I saw that the Meteor framework uses the Clojurescript library Mori since version 0.9 and was wondering if anyone can explain why this is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in the constraint solver used in 0.9's package system. I found the commit where it was first added. It appears to be used to improve performance, as the commit message states:

> Use persistent data-structures on the back-end of these classes to reduce the
>   time spent on copy-on-write operations.
>
> After this change the performance decreased on smaller tests, increased
>   drastically on bigger tests (up to 50% improvement on the largest test) but
>   increased the memory consumption by a negligible amount.

That commit can be found [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/a70065c324ccc491fef379ceaf925145dbc78e78).

Comment: SO does this mean that the whole real time persistence system needs a persistent data structure to function? Otherwise it would not be "real time"